# List size error

Tags: android, listview

I wrote code that fetches keys from a Firebase database and writes them to a `ListView` component. There is a simple problem that I cannot solve.

My code is below. Can someone please help me with this?

```
List<String> list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView rooms_list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rooms_list);

    rooms_list = findViewById(R.id.rooms_list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.rooms_list_layout, list);

    DatabaseReference mref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chatRooms");
    mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                list.add(snapshot.getKey());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    rooms_list.setAdapter(adapter);


}

}
```

Comment: Yeah, not sure what the question is? Please be more specific.

Comment: To help people answer your question, please be more specific about what issue you are having. Are you getting an error (if so, post the error and indicate what line it's coming from if applicable)? Is it running, but not working as intended?

Comment: `simple proble`  what is the problem? Should we guess? WHy?

Comment: The list you pass to your ArrayAdapter is not initialized.  But, yeah - we're just guessing without more information about what you think the problem is.